# Whitney embedding for manifolds with boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Suppose one has a smooth manifold with boundary M and compact on top of it. Is it true that it can always be embedded in an upper half plane such that the boundary is embedded in the hiperplane $x_n=0$? Or are there obstructions to that? If yes, what are those obstructions? Thank you!

Comment: Uhhh, if you Whitney-embed M into a large enough Euclidean space $R^n$, then embed that into $R^n\times R$, doesnt this do it? assuming the hyperplane is part of the "upper half space".

Comment: As Chris mentions, there's no obstruction.  You can embed an $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary in a Euclidean half-space of dimension $2n$ "neatly" as you describe.   And embeddings are generic if the half-space has dimension $k > 2n$.  

Comment: Daniel probably wants to know that the interior can 
be mapped in the (strictly) upper half space. This is a 
consequence of the collaring theorem: the boundary of M has a neighborhood homeo (or diffeo) to 
$\partial M\times [0,1)$. This can extended over $M$ and
 used as a last coordinate.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.
That is exactly what I wanted, Paul! Shall I understand that the proof of Whitney's theorem goes thru without  any headaches, other than what you just said?

Comment: That's correct.  It's the same proof, just with one (small) extra layer of complexity that doesn't get in the way of any essential steps. 

Answer (score 5):

See  Theorem 1.4.3. of

> M. Hirsch: Differential Topology, Springer Verlag, 1976